# Is there a lightweight way to get a handle to the context to get a resource?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, android-context

My ship class needs to get a bitmap from the resources folder so I pass that into the constructor like this:

```
public Ship(Context context) {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.myShipPic);
    ...
```

I'd like to not have to pass in a context object and have the ship class more self contained, how is this possible? I don't think I can have the ship extend an Activity class because that's for creating windows, right?

Comment: `I don't think I can have the ship extend an Activity class because thats for creating windows right`: That's correct. Your current implementation is not wrong and as far as I know there's no other way to do it. Remember that if you're passing `Context` to other objects that you do not end up with circular references

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [blog entry](https://www.fwd.cloud/commit/post/android-context-on-demand/) about why the context should be used *on demand*, so that's the way to go, you need to pass the context either in the constructor or in the method. Don't retrieve the context statically, because one day your app will crash and then you'll have to refactor all the code to retrieve it *on demand* instead. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Also, get used to retrieve the application context from the passed context, don't use the context directly. It's fine as long as your class doesn't keep a reference to the passed context; you can keep a reference to the application context instead. Like this:

`public Ship(@NonNull Context context) {
      Context appCtx = context.getApplicationContext();`